# There are 5 blocks in each SWIFT-MT message, so why in the specification, it needs up to 3 alphanumeric letters for the block indentifier?

Tags: swift-mt

I read from this [post](https://www.paiementor.com/swift-mt-message-structure-blocks-1-to-5/)

and in the Standards MT November 2022 - General Information, page #48
[image: MT 103 structure example]

So there are max at 5 blocks for each message. So can anybody please tell why the specification needs up to 3 alphanumeric letters for the block indentifier?

ex: [description of the SWIFT MT Message Block 1](https://www.paiementor.com/swift-mt-message-block-1-basic-header-description/) (same for other blocks), the block identifier content is '3c'.